# Configurar dominios internacionales con WPML

Tags: wordpress

buenos días

Tenemos el siguiente escenario alojado bajo PLESK.

- **dominio.com**: WEB principal donde está alojada la WEB en WORDPRESS. TIENE SSL activo.

Además, tenemos dominios internacionales tipo:

- dominio.pt
- dominio.fr
- dominio.it

Queremos configurar con el WPML que cada idioma se muestre en un dominio, para ello hemos seguido estos pasos:https://wpml.org/es/faq/configuracion-del-servidor-para-idiomas-en-distintos-dominios/

**¿Cuál es el problema?**

Que al estar el dominio.com con SSL activo y el resto de dominios bajo un SERVERALIAS, al entrar en, por ejemplo, dominio.pt da error de "web insegura"... ¿qué podemos hacer? Al ser un Alias no se puede instalar un SSL (al menos eso nos han dicho)... :?

¡Gracias!

Comment: Te recomiendo preguntar en el foro de wpml, suelen responder con rapidez, y ellos son los primeros interesados en dar ese servicio ;)

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente el certificado SSL solo se puede habilitar para un dominio que tenga un hosting asociado. Para un dominio alias no es posible. Una recomendación podría ser manejar el tema de los lenguajes con subdominios por ejemplo si el visitante abre el sitio dominio.fr se redirija a fr.dominio.com o también podría ser a dominio.com/fr/